# Is ARIMA model appropriate for this dental research?

Tags: time-series, arima

Please, I have a doubt in my study for doctoral thesis…

Title: “Development of a thermal cycling protocol for dental materials”.
Objective: to create a protocol for thermal aging, from measurements that were found in people mouth. 
Doubt: What analyses could I use for this variation temperature data?
Experimental unit: six volunteers 
Variable: temperature

A student of PhD in dentistry did a work to describe an average pattern of temperature (°C) variation in the oral cavity of six volunteers.

She collected oral temperature data (°C) for 3 days, in 6 patients at each 4 of 4 seconds.

The aim is to establish an average pattern of temperature variation, according to the time, temperature variation and the number of changes per day.

The patients have different routines of each others and per day, so, is there any statistical analyses that I can establish a standard protocol with her data?

Basically, she would like to find an answer like as: A person, on average, per day, has three temperature increases of 40°C , which was maintained for 40 seconds, and 3 temperature decreases from 16°C maintained for 40 seconds.

Is ARIMA test appropriate for this study?
If not, is there another solution it?

Comment: I believe that There is no expert here, in this fórum, about your question.
Sorry
Ivan

Comment: Just to clarify - you have data collected every 4 seconds over 3 days? So, 15*60*24*3 measurements per person ?

Comment: I have 6 volunteers, in 3 days, and it's measure 12 hours of temperature. So,  I have about 6*3*10800 measurements, because 12 hours have 43200 seconds, and 43200 is divided for 4 seconds.